# overloaded bracket operator for std::list

Tags: c++

I was wondering how I would go about creating an overloaded bracket operator that would provide the location of an element in an std::list.

the list declaration in my class is as follows:

```
std::list<Stimulation*> configuration;
```

the overloaded bracket operator declaration is:

```
std::list<Stimulation*>::operator[](const int);
```

I would figure that the defintion of the bracket operator would go as follows:

```
std::list<Stimulation*>::operator[](const int position)
{
  auto i = configuration.begin();
  return i + position;

  ***OR***

  std::list<Stimulation*>::iterator i = configuration.begin();
  return i + position;
}
```

I am new to this concept so any help would be appreciated in the proper way of doing this. I am required to specifically use a list in this situation as I know other containers include the bracket operator as part of the library. Thanks again for your patience and time.

Comment: there's a reason why there's no bracket operator for `list`. It's because of the need to go from element to element, so O(n) access. You have to loop using a `for`, counting how many elements you're iterating.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: ya i read that but this specification that I am getting is asking for that, so I was not sure what do exactly.

Comment: the spec is: An overloaded operator to access Stimulation objects using []

Comment: There is a function [std::advance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) that will move your iterator to the right position. But it is expensive to use for `std::list::iterator`. If direct access is important, why not use a `std::vector<Stimulation*>` instead? A list has no real advantage for storing pointers.

Comment: I understand but this is for a course I am taking and it is emphasizing to use a list and then asking for the spec I previously mentioned with the overloaded operator using [].

Comment: I will look into std::advance as well

Comment: Class interfaces should be easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly. If you provide an `operator[]`, a user might often do random accesses inside the list, which is the incorrect way to use a list.

Comment: If you haven't done so, please implement a (singly or doubly) linked list. When done, you will instantly see, why there is no random access operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::list` elements are not contiguous in memory, unlike `std::vector` elements, that's why no `[]` operator exists because it would be inefficient, and that's not why lists are made for.

But, as an exercise, you could implement it with a `for` loop. Here's my naive implementation, lacking `const` version, and failing with an assertion when out of bounds:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class MyList : public list<int>
{
public:

    int &operator[](int pos)
    {
       int count=0;
       for (auto &it : *this)
       {
          if (count==pos) { return it;}
          count++;
       }
     assert(false);
   }
};


int main()
{
    MyList l;
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(3);
    l.push_back(4);
    cout << l[2] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Access time is very bad if element is at the end of the list (`O(N)`) because you cannot add position to `list::begin()`.

I suppose you could "cache" the last asked offset & iterator so if caller asks for offset+1 (which is frequent in programs) you can just advance without resuming from the start.

Note: just saw the comment about `std::advance`. Not used there (didn't know it).

Comment: This is more of what I was looking for thanks. This course does things in an unorthodox way to really understand the theoretical aspects of how things work I am guessing, not necessarily the right way. Appreciate the time.

Comment: it's still interesting to know how to do such things, yes. A former colleague of mine had the idea of defining division operator on a custom string class to concatenate directories with filenames. The result was very readable: `dirname / basename` whereas it had nothing to do with division.

Comment: ya that definitely is interesting and it most certainly gets you thinking about the multitude of ways that you can get a language to implement and idea that one might have. Thanks again!